# Как реализовать слушателя, который будет реагировать на отдельный элемент RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Я не могу реализовать слушателя Recycler View, который будет реагировать на отдельные его элементы. Вот допустим у меня есть Recycler View  из четырех  элементов, я хочу по нажатия открывался разные фрагменты.

> Я пытался юзaть это код:

```
public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {
    TextView mText;
    Button mButton;
    CardView mCard;

public ItemHolder(View v) {
    super(v);

    mCard = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_card);
    mText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
    mButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.item_button);

    mCard.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

 }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int position = getAdapterPosition();
    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.card:
                itemClick(position);
                break;
            case R.id.button:
                buttonClick(position);
        }
    }
}

private void itemClick(int position){

 //action on item click
}

private void buttonClick (int position){

  //action on button click
}


 }
```

> Вдобавок я не могу понять, какие id надо юзать:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.card:
                    itemClick(position);
                    break;
                case R.id.button:
                    buttonClick(position);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Так как Вы реализовали то клик на элемент?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```
switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.item_card:
                itemClick(position);
                break;
            case R.id.item_button:
                buttonClick(position);
        }
```